# Google OAuth Developer Verification Form with private home page

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-api-client, google-oauth

I have "unverified app screen" when I request access to Google accounts. 
To get rid of it I want to fill out [OAuth Developer Verification Form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification?authuser=2). But, I got some problems with that due to some restrictions on my environment.

There is a field:

> Homepage URL for your app *

The problem is that in my application my home page is not accessible publicly. Usually, it can only be accessed using VPN connection.
For push notifications, I use different URL that only handles them, but for the UI there is no access from the world without VPN. I was thinking of overcoming the issue and have a few ideas, but I'm not sure whether they will work.

1. Inform Google of restricted access to the home page via this field:

> Is there any other information you can provide that will be useful?

However, this approach might not work due to the fact that it's not said that I can omit to specify the home page.

2. Find out what addresses google requests homepage from and to allow access to it from those addresses. But, firstly it's insecure and secondly, it's still a question how to get these addresses.
3. Make some static resource stub page and place it somewhere where I can provide access. For instance, I can put it near privacy policy file that is publicly accessible.

Is there a more suitable way of addressing this issue or some of these options might still work?